# Is there a way I can retain maximum distinct values by finding optimal filters on other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new to Python. I have a column with 10000 unique values and I would like to retain as many of those values as possible. My other fields are ratios between  0 and 1 but I don't know what would be ideal filters that would allow me to reduce the number of records and still retain most of my unique values.

**x**       **y**     **z**

**a05**    0.9   0.5

**a06**    0.5   0.4

**a05**    0.6   0.1

I have multiple duplicate records for each value of X. I would like my output to be a threshold for y and z (like y = 0.6 and z = 0.1) I'm trying to reduce the number of duplicates and not necessarily have just one field for each unique value of X. It's more important that I retain as many unique values for x with the filters. Is there a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Always try to post example code that you have tried and example output that you're expecting whenever possible. It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Could you be more specific about which records you want to remove and which you want to retain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use pandas [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), so you can remove duplicate values based on a subset of columns.